# What version of PHP introduced the <?php tag?

Tags: php

I'm creating a test server for a new client that has and older version of PHP that only uses the `<?` tags but the latest version of PHP is expecting `<?php` tags.

I'm looking for the version I need to install so that I can run the old code without changing any of it.

Comment: Your text is a bit wonky - can you please surround the <?php (or whatever you put in your question) inside `backticks`, or else use the editor to mark it as code?  It's gone invisible.

Comment: To answer the question in the subject line: PHP 1.0. ;)

Comment: @Frank I was confused as well after reading it the first time. Took care of it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just need to enable [*short_open_tag*](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) to use that short version of the standard PHP tags `<?php`.

But I wouldn’t do that but just replace the short tags `<?` with the standard PHP tags `<?php` for portability.

Comment: You are correct, just be careful replacing '<?' with '<?php' to ensure that you also replace '<?=' with '<?php echo' since <?php= does not work.

Comment: Adding to @Wally, you don't want to replace the `<?` in <?xml` either.

Answer (score 6):

To the best of my knowledge, `<?php` has always been available. `<?` aka short tags are only available when the directive is allowed in php.ini

Answer (score 3):

the short tag can be used in any version of PHP. You just need to allow it in the php.ini: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity I downloaded some of the older versions of PHP from the [museum](http://museum.php.net/), and all of the examples in version 'php-2.0' only used `<?` to open the tags.  So I'm going to assume version 1.0 and 2.0 only used `<?` and `<?php` was introduced in either a later version of 2 or 3.0.

I really wouldn't suggest using any of the old versions of PHP though, mess around with the php.ini and you should be able to get the script working on 4.0.